# Защита apk от декомпиляции

Tags: java, android, apk, декомпиляция

Подскажите самые простые из существующих методов защиты для скрытия (шифровки, нечитаемости и пр.) хотябы одного файла `strings.xml`

Comment: Вы собираетесь что-то тайное хранить в открытом виде в strings.xml?

Comment: ProGuard, DexGuard

Comment: @Evgen Orlovsky в отношении ко всему коду там самая ценная информация) на сколько я цнаю, тут обсуждений быть не должно, только на конкретный вопрос конкретный ответ

Comment: @Shwarz Andrei про ProGuard знаю, а вот DexGuard не в курсе был, посмотрю

Comment: @ЕвгенийМ. конкретный ответ - все имеющиеся средства "защиты" взламываются, в вашем случае, менее чем за 5 минут.